# How to reduce runtime of parallellizable code in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a program with some parts parallelizable. I want to run it in parallel (not concurrent) to reduce runtime.

I tried Multi-threading `threading.Thread` & multi-processing `processing.Process`. But the runtime of the code is not improving. I'm fact, it's getting a little worse (single-threaded runtime is being better than multi-threaded & multi-processed).

Can I do something to reduce the runtime?

Here are the explanation of my code & the code itself:

Basically, I have a 2D array & I have to run a function (`check_occ_for_division`) on each element of it. This function's run on an element of the array is independent of the run on other elements of the array.

So, I divide the map into 4 divisions & run the function on (the elements of) each division in a separate thread.

```
from spatialmath import SE3
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import time

from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process

def dummy():
    '''A function to simulate runtime of the original function'''
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return True

def transform_pose_to_a_different_coordinate_frame(pose):
    '''Actual function does some coordinate transformations. Redacting it for convenience & just returning the input pose'''
    return pose

def check_occlusions_for_division(x_range, y_range, occlusions):
    print(x_range, y_range)
    for observer_x in x_range:
        for observer_y in y_range:
            observer_pose = SE3((observer_x, observer_y, observer_z))
            observer_pose = transform_pose_to_a_different_coordinate_frame(observer_pose)
            for observee_x in range(array_width):
                for observee_y in range(array_height):
                    observee_pose = SE3(observee_x, observee_y, observee_z)
                    observee_pose = transform_pose_to_a_different_coordinate_frame(observee_pose)
                    occluded = dummy() # check_occlusion(observer_pose_omap, observee_pose_omap)
                    # Actually, the above variable `occluded` is calculated by another function `check_occlusion` in a little complex way.
                    # But I'm just skipping that function for convenience.
                    # As, I don't intend to make any modifications to that function to improve runtime.
                    
                    if occluded:
                        occlusions[observer_x][observer_y].append([observee_x, observee_y])

            occlusions[observer_x][observer_y] = np.array(occlusions[observer_x][observer_y])
    return occlusions


omap_res = 0.1
array_width = 61
array_height = 61
observer_z = 3
observee_z = 0.1

num_threads = 4
assert sqrt(num_threads) == int(sqrt(num_threads))

'''Split the array into `num_threads` divisions'''

# Here, I'm just preparing some variables to split the square array into 4 divisions
num_x_divisions = int(sqrt(num_threads))
num_y_divisions = int(sqrt(num_threads))
x_div_size = array_width // num_x_divisions
y_div_size = array_height // num_y_divisions
div_ranges = []

for i in range(num_x_divisions):
    for j in range(num_y_divisions):
        div_x_range = range(i*x_div_size, (i+1)*x_div_size if i!=num_x_divisions-1 else array_width)
        div_y_range = range(j*y_div_size, (j+1)*y_div_size if j!=num_y_divisions-1 else array_height)
        div_ranges.append((div_x_range, div_y_range))

'''Run the function on each division on a separate thread / process'''
occlusions = np.empty((int(array_width), int(array_height), 0)).tolist()
threads = []
for thread_idx in range(num_threads):
    (div_x_range, div_y_range) = div_ranges[thread_idx]
    t = Thread(target=check_occlusions_for_division, args=(div_x_range, div_y_range, occlusions))
    # t = Process(target=check_occlusions_for_division, args=(div_x_range, div_y_range, occlusions))
    threads.append(t)

threads[0].start()
threads[1].start()
threads[2].start()
threads[3].start()

threads[0].join()
threads[1].join()
threads[2].join()
threads[3].join()
```

Comment: You can achieve parallelism by using multiprocessing (not easily with multithreading). If this didn't help, then the overhead of using it was greater than the benefits of running in parallel.

Comment: Multiprocessing in CPython is often slow due to inter-process communication (i.e. IPC) and pickling/unpickling (i.e. serialisation). Multi-threading in CPython is bound by the GIL so any computational operation cannot be speed up unless the GIL is released (often not). Parallelism is a mess in Python. There is maybe a solution for you but we can't tell with the provided informations. Please share more infos about the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Edited the question to include my code & explanation. Thanks!

Comment: You are using multithreading which means that you are not getting true parallel execution.

Comment: It's also possible that NumPy already uses parallelism behind the scenes without you using multithreading or multiprocessing and this is why you don't get an improvement.

Comment: I tried multi-processing too (by uncommenting the `    # t = Process(target=check_occlusions_for_division, args=(div_x_range, div_y_range, occlusions))` line & commenting the `Thread` line above it). But even then no improvement

Comment: The function `check_occlussion()` that I actually use in place of `dummy()`, takes up good amount of time & it is this time that I hope to reduce by parallelism. I don't think numpy parallelism has to do anything with it?

Comment: It uses NumPy data structures and operations, which may already be parallelized if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It does have a few numpy operations (not many). But it also has ray tracing which forms the bulk of the runtime.

Comment: Regarding the kind of computation you are doing Numba and Cython are the way to go. Here, Numpy should release the GIL but the benefit will be small and I thing you may not even see a benefit due to the fine-grained vectorization, if any. Numba/Cython can disable the GIL (but it require you not to use any CPython object in the computing parts).

Comment: @jeromeRichard do you mean fine grain vectorization by "regarding the kind of computation you are doing"?

Comment: What do you mean by "fine grain vectorization" ? The term "vectorization" [defined by Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-vectorization) mainly applies in CPython but not much in Numba/Cython functions which are (mostly) not interpreted. A generic Numba/Cython function can be seen are an extension of the Numpy API.